# Assign each letter in array to divs from querySelector All

Tags: javascript, css

I have 6 divs in my HTML each suppsoed to hold their own letter.

I have a query selector to capture all the divs.  I looped through all the divs, created a div for each and I want to assign the letters from the array to each div respectively.  Its only showing S though, can anyone assist?

Basically for every DIV, I want there to be 1 letter spelling the word "Smiley" from the array

```
let charDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");


let createLetters = () => {
  let smiley = ["S", "M", "I", "L", "E", "Y"];

   charDivs.forEach(el => {
    let circle = document.createElement("DIV");

    circle.style.cssText = "position:relative;font-size:2rem;font-weight:bold";
    circle.textContent = "s";
    smiley.forEach(el => (circle.textContent = el));
    el.appendChild(circle);
  });
};
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you won't do `<div>SMILEY</div>` simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
let charDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");


let createLetters = () => {
  let smiley = ["S", "M", "I", "L", "E", "Y"];

   charDivs.forEach((el,indx) => {
    let circle = document.createElement("DIV");

    circle.style.cssText = "position:relative;font-size:2rem;font-weight:bold";
    // Use the charDiv index to extract corresponding letter from smiley array
    // You can add some verification if the index is in the allowed range (smiley.length)
    circle.textContent = smiley[indx];
    el.appendChild(circle);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're creating a new div.

Here I've used the index from the `forEach` to grab the right element from the smiley array, and add a CSS class to the circle. I also added an `inline-block` statement to the CSS so the text runs horizontally.

```js
let charDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

function createLetters() {
  let smiley = ["S", "M", "I", "L", "E", "Y"];
   charDivs.forEach((circle, i) => {
    circle.classList.add('circle');
    circle.textContent = smiley[i];
  });
}

createLetters();
```

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  font-size:2rem;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: `position:relative;` seems like krap

Comment: This is perfect.  All i needed to do was add the I argument to the foreach method

circle.textContent = smiley[i];

Comment: Im creating a new DIV cause its gonna be a DIV inside a DIV.  One div will have background colors and the next div inside will have only the letter - thats why, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution using a traditional for loop
And unlike the other answers, mine checks to make sure you haven't exceeded the bounds of your array (smiley)

```
let charDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div");


let createLetters = () => {
  let smiley = ["S", "M", "I", "L", "E", "Y"];
  //Use traditional for-loop
  for(let x = 0; x < charDivs.length; x++){
      let circle = document.createElement("DIV");
      circle.style.cssText = "position:relative;font-size:2rem;font-weight:bold";
      circle.textContent = x > charDivs.length - 1 ? smiley[x % (charDivs.length - 1)] : smiley[x]; //Just in case you ever had more divs than you do values in the smiley array
      charDivs[x].appendChild(circle);
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `.forEach`, all you need to do is append the properties to the `el` variable. When you create a new one, the `charDivs` is essentially useless. You could simply remove the circle variable and use the above answer, OR

```js
function createLetters() {
  let smiley = ["S", "M", "I", "L", "E", "Y"];
  smiley.forEach((letter) => {
    let charDiv = document.createElement("div");
    charDiv.textContent = letter;
    charDiv.classList.add('circle');
    document.body.appendChild(charDiv);
  });
}

createLetters();
```

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block; /* You can change this to block if you want one on each line */ 
  position:relative;
  font-size:2rem;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

I would not even create the div manually because you can also loop that! Don't forget to use `document.body.appendChild()` at the end, or then it won't show anything!